# Special characters when importing from BigQuery to R

Tags: r, twitter, google-bigquery

I have a script for scrapping some tweets and saving the results to Google BigQuery. When I see the stored data, special characters like ➕, ‍♂️, Ñ, áéíóú appear correctly, but when I try to import the data again to R they are replaced by some strange characters. Here's an example.

```
# Create df

id_tweet <- 1023985670224785408
tweet <- "◉ Neuroeducación y entornos digitales de aprendizaje: un paso obligado para educadores, pedagogos y psicólogos"
descripcion <- "Desde las alturas se ve todo de otra manera... ️ ➕ ‍♂️"

data <- data.frame(id, tweet, description)

# Save to Google BQ

library(bigrquery)

insert_upload_job("project-id", "dataset", "table", data , write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND")

#Load from Gooble BQ

sql <- paste("SELECT *", "FROM", "`project-id.dataset.table`")
data <- query_exec(sql, project = "project-id", use_legacy_sql = FALSE)
```

My output is the following:

```
> data
               id_tweet
283 1023985670224785408
                                                                                                                                         tweet
283 â—‰ NeuroeducaciÃ³n y entornos digitales de aprendizaje: un paso obligado para educadores, pedagogos y psicÃ³logos
                                                                                        descripcion
283 Desde las alturas se ve todo de otra manera... ï¿½ï¿½ï¸ âž• ï¿½ï¿½<U+200D>â™‚ï¸ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½
```

What I want is to keep the original format.

What should I do?

Thanks,

Comment: I could try this code in my end and everything worked fine for me. I have changed `id` and `despcription` in dataframe construction for `id_tweet` and `descripcion` but I think it was typo in your question. Could you output data just after execute this command `data <- data.frame(id, tweet, description)`? also check schema of your BQ table

Answer (score 0):

I tested a few things which may help.

Firstly, I saved the blank R script and ensured it was in UTF-8 encoding: File -> Save with Encoding -> UTF-8. Then saved just the special characters in your question in double quotes as a .csv (i.e. `"➕, ‍♂️, Ñ, áéíóú"`). Then read in the csv with `fileEncoding = "UTF-8"`, i.e:

```
test <- read.csv("test.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Inside R Studio, `test` returns:

```
# > test
# V1
# 1 \u2795, ‍♂️, Ñ, áéíóú
```

So all but the ➕ display nicely in R Studio. However, a lot of characters, even common ones like line breaks, and tabs etc display funnily in RStudio but normally when a file is written. These are no different.

When the csv is written (just using `write.csv(test, 'test2.csv', row.names=FALSE)`), it displays perfectly as it did in the original csv (that's when opened in sublime text)

After all this, I would suggest ensuring your encoding is UTF-8, and perhaps trying to save the BQ output as a csv (if possible?) and inspecting it to see if the issue is coming from BQ or R. If it comes out of BQ correctly, then it should be simply a matter of changing the encoding in RStudio. But if it's not coming out of BQ as intended, then I'd suggest you need to change the datatype in BQ (to UTF-8)

Comment: Thanks! but I keep having the same issue. My solution is to save the table in a Google Sheet. I have to do it manually, but life is not always beautiful...

Comment: @FrancescPonsÁlvarez I guess you are reading data from `Google Sheet` now and it solves your issue. Could you find the cause of this? If it is working on `Google Sheet` but not on `BQ`, I would suggest to review encoding configuration when loading from `BQ table`

Answer (score 0):

After 6 months, I finally managed to solve this problem. Instead of using the function `query_exec` i used `bq_table_download` from the same package instead. This function solves the problem.